# Trying to create a texture sorter in python

Tags: python

*Trying to sort image files based on their names, but i just can't figure it out. I'm no good at coding or python so i've just been using Codium to help me with the code but of course AI can only help you so much until you get stuck. The issue i have is i want to sort images based on unique names, and i want the sorter to detect if it has certain names inside of the title of the image... let me give an example

BaseColor.Tree-uv.jpg

Normal.Tree-uv.jpg

opacity.window.1001.jpg

So basically what i want the sorter to do is to scan the folder with all the images, then detect all Basecolor, normal, ambient and opacity maps(and the rest if i can fill it in). Then read the second name of the image which would be the Unique name and also the name of the folder it would go in, so for example, folders will be created called "Tree-uv" and "window.1001". So i know that i can use the separators "." and it would be nice to make this able to change for other files that have separators of "_". Also these folders will then have their corresponding files inside of them. :D please dont roast me too hard, its my first time posting here :D

this is the code i have now:*

```
import os
import re
import shutil
from collections import defaultdict

def organize_textures(input_folder, output_folder, separator, unique_name_first):
    files = os.listdir(input_folder)
    image_files = [f for f in files if f.lower().endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif', '.bmp'))]
    
    file_groups = defaultdict(list)
    for file in image_files:
        file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file)  
        unique_name, _ = extract_unique_name_and_texture_type(file_name, separator, unique_name_first)
        file_groups[unique_name].append((file, file_extension))

    for unique_name, file_list in file_groups.items():
        unique_name = unique_name.replace(".1001", "").replace(".2001", "")
        for file, file_extension in file_list:
            folder_name = unique_name
            folder_path = os.path.join(output_folder, folder_name)
            os.makedirs(folder_path, exist_ok=True)  
            source_path = os.path.join(input_folder, file)
            destination_filename = file
            destination_path = os.path.join(folder_path, destination_filename)
            if os.path.isdir(source_path):
                shutil.copytree(source_path, destination_path)  
            else:
                shutil.move(source_path, destination_path)

def extract_unique_name_and_texture_type(file_name, separator, unique_name_first):
    unique_name = ""
    texture_type = ""
    pattern = construct_regex(separator)

    match = re.match(pattern, file_name)
    if match:
        parts = file_name.split(separator)
        for part in parts:
            if part not in texture_types:
                unique_name += part + separator
            else:
                texture_type += part + separator
        
        unique_name = unique_name.rstrip(separator)
        texture_type = texture_type.rstrip(separator)
    else:
        unique_name = file_name
        texture_type = 'default'
    
    return unique_name, texture_type

def construct_regex(separator):
    return r"(.+)\\" + re.escape(separator) + r"(.+)\.(.+)"

# Example usage
input_folder = ""
output_folder = ""
separator = "."
texture_types = ["Basecolor", "Metallic", "Roughness", "Normal", "AO"]
unique_name_first = False

organize_textures(input_folder, output_folder, separator, unique_name_first)
```

Like ive said, ive been using codium and though its helped me alot and a few times i came very close, i just cant figure it out.